# Use Props Callback with react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would like to know how can I pass callback with react native please.

Currently I have 3 components :

MessageTypeText.js -> MessageButtons.js -> MessageButton.js

> 1 MessageButton.js

```
export default class MessageButton extends React.Component {

    clickButton(button) {
        console.log('message button');
        this.props.callBackFunction('PAYLOAD' , button.payload);
    }

    render() {
        let button = this.props.button;

        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.clickButton(button)}>
                <Text>
                    { button.title }
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}
```

> 2 MessageButtons.js

```
export default class MessageButtons extends React.Component {

    sendMessageToAPI(messageType, data) {
        console.log('message buttons');
        this.props.callBackMessageButtons(messageType , data);
    }

    renderButtons(buttons) {
        return(buttons.map((button, indexButton) => {
            return <MessageButton key={indexButton}
                                  button={button}
                                  callBackFunction={this.sendMessageToAPI} />
        }))
    }

    ...
}
```

> 3 MessageTypeText.js

```
export default class MessageTypeText extends React.Component {

    sendMessageToAPI(messageType, data) {
        console.log('message type text');
        //this.props.callBackFunction(messageType , data);
    }

    renderButtons(message) {
        if(...){
        return (<MessageButtons buttons={message.attachment.payload.buttons}
                                                callBackMessageButtons={this.sendMessageToAPI} />)
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

When I click on TouchableOpacity in component MessageButton.js (more deeply), I see in my console :

message button,
message buttons

but I don't see :

message type text

And I have this error :

> Cannot read property 'callBackMessageButtons' of undefined (MessageButtons.js (line 10)

I can execute **this.props.callBackMessageButtons(messageType , data);** in **MessageButtons.js**

I use the arrow function in my render, but I have always this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not forget about binding your callbacks. Or just use arrow function:

```
sendMessageToAPI = (messageType, data) => {
    console.log('message buttons');
    this.props.callBackMessageButtons(messageType , data);
}
```

That's necessary to make `this` work in the callback as you would expect.

Comment: Thank you so much !